# Ajax Request Unsupported_grant_type

Tags: jquery, ajax, token

I'm doing some code in javascript and i intend to do a method that send a request to a web api and receive a token in return (not done yet).

This is my code

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,   //For cors on web api
    crossOrigin: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true,  //send the credentials
    },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    url: 'https://localhost:44123/Token',
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: username,
    password: password,
    success: function () {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //Add these parameters to display the required response
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },
});
```

But everytime i execute the method i receive the following errors:

Error 400(Post) --> unsupported_grant_type

I'm not used to ajax/js ... so i'm a litle bit lost.. Any ideas?
 -

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass `grant_type`, `username` and `password` as part of your POST parameter and not as an `$.ajax` parameter as you are currently doing.

Try this:

```
var body = {
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: username,
    password: password
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:44123/Token',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    /* data: JSON.stringify(body), /* wrong */
    data: body, /* right */
    complete: function(result) {
        //called when complete
        alert(result);
    },

    success: function(result) {
        //called when successful
        alert(result);
    },

    error: function(result) {
        //called when there is an error
        alert(result);
    },
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks for the explanation and your time @IzzEps. I will accept you answer as the correct one.